# Underscore JS _.partial reduce maintaining memo reference and casting integers to string?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, pass-by-reference

Given the following (simplified) code, attempting to dynamically calculate a bootstrap grid:

```
(function() {
    var reduceCalc = _.partial(_.reduce, _, function(memo, entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        console.log((_.last(memo) + parseInt(entry)));
        if (!entry || (parseInt(_.last(memo) + parseInt(entry)) <= 12)) {
            _.last(memo).push(entry);
        } else {
            memo.push([entry]);
        }
        return memo;
    }, [
        []
    ]);

    var oneList = [6, 6];
    var twoList = [7, 5, 4, 6];

    var rowListOne = reduceCalc(oneList);
    var rowListTwo = reduceCalc(twoList);

    console.log(rowListOne);
    console.log(rowListTwo);

})();
```

Two questions,

1. The `parseInt` is necessary, because without it the second console log: `console.log((_.last(memo) + entry));` casts both integers as strings and returns "66", "75". Why does it do that?
2. The second, and really much more major question is: why does it appear to maintain a reference to memo, rather then resetting it as [[]] per run? The final console logs are:

   ```
   [Array[0], Array[2], Array[3], Array[1]]
   [Array[0], Array[2], Array[3], Array[1]]
   ```

Why does it maintain this reference? How can I avoid it doing so? Demo plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DTbgrIsg4MILGuoaureU?p=preview

Comment: Isn't `_.chain(memo).last().value()` the same as `memo[memo.length-1]`? The later is shorter...

Comment: _.last(memo) is in fact even shorter (let me fix that) the chain is a hangover from my actual code which then goes on to apply a reduce as it is not an array of integer, but field schema JSVs.

Good spot though, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at this `parseInt` stuff first. The underlying problem is what sort of things you're storing in `memo`:

```
memo.push([entry])
```

So the entries of `memo` are single element arrays and `_.last(memo)` will be an array. If you try to `array + something_else` you'll end up with coercing everything to strings and doing string concatenation because, more or less, everything ends up getting stringified when JavaScript doesn't know what else to do. You want to look inside the arrays inside `memo`:

```
console.log(_.last(memo)[0] + entry)
```

Keep in mind that `console.log` is variadic so you could also say:

```
console.log(_.last(memo), entry)
```

That could leave you with confusing live references in the console so maybe this would be better:

```
console.log(_.clone(_.last(memo)), entry)
```

Your second problem is a reference problem. You're saying things:

```
var fn = function(memo,entry) { ... };
var aoa = [ [ ] ];
var reduceCalc = _.partial(_.reduce, _, fn, aoa);
```

That `aoa` array will be stashed inside `reduceCalc` and that exact array will be used by every invocation of `reduceCalc`. There's nothing anywhere in your code that will create a new array for each invocation.

If you want a new array then you'd need to do something like this:

```
var reduceCalc = _.partial(_.reduce, _, function(memo, entry) {
    memo = memo || [ [ ] ]; // Create a new array specific to this invocation
    //...
    return memo;
}, null);
```

The odd looking `null` is needed to trick `_.reduce` into supplying a `null` value for `memo` the first time it calls the callback, `_.reduce` will use its argument's first entry as the initial `memo` if you don't specify an explicit one.